# The quality of beer from one gallon brewing equipment versus more robust equipment

Tags: brewing

I'm becoming more interested in brewing my own beer and due to space considerations am thinking a 1-gallon size may be my ideal choice of setup.

The question is:

**In what ways does brewing with 1 gallon equipment effect the quality of beer that's produced, as opposed to brewing from more robust and expensive setups?**

edit: May have used the 'kit' terminology in a way I didn't intend. Basically what I'm asking is if 1 gallon equipment will produce a lesser quality beer than a more expensive, and bigger setup.

Comment: you should also ask this at https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/ where I am also active. Been brewing beer for 25 years...

Comment: Done and done..

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on a lot of factors, but you should be able to make high quality beer. You just have to pay a lot of attention to detail. Measuring ingredients becomes super important. A little error can screw up a beer. In bigger batches there is more room for error. Same with mashing. You need to have a really good way to keep the mash at the proper temperature, which can be hard in a small container. Otherwise, there is no reason a 1 gallon batch can't be just as good.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've been brewing for more than a year. I already did 1 gallon to 5 gallons, the quality of the beer is the same. You must pay attention in all proccess not just in the used kit.

My friends and I use a simple kit, to make the beer most archaic. Except the first time, the others results were very good.

I talk more of the beers that we made in https://sommelieria.wordpress.com/. It's in Portuguese but can help you.